# Image of a unit disk under a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is the following:

Prove that the image of the disk $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|\leq1\}$ under the function $f(z)=\cos z$ is contained in the disk $D'=\{w \in \mathbb{C} : |w|\leq(e^2+1)/(2e)\}$. (Hint: $e^{-|z|}\leq|e^z|\leq e^{|z|}$, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$)

By the definition, we have
$$
|w|=|\cos z|=\frac{1}{2}\left|e^{zi}+e^{-zi}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}(|e^{zi}|+|e^{-zi}|).
$$
Now, using the hint,
\begin{equation}
|w|\leq\frac{1}{2}(e^{|zi|}+e^{-|zi|}).
\end{equation}
And then, as $z\in D$, we have $|zi|=|z||i|=|z|\leq1$. Therefore
$$
|w|\leq\frac{1}{2}(e^{|zi|}+e^{-|zi|})\leq\frac{1}{2}(e+e^{-1})=\frac{e^2+1}{2e}.
$$

But I am not sure that I may use the hint to conclude that $|e^{-zi}|\leq e^{-|zi|}$. Can anyone have another solution to give me or even how to prove this inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the hint is useful. Write $z=x+iy.$ Then

$$\tag 1 |\cos z| = |e^{iz}+ e^{-iz}|/2 \le (|e^{iz}|+ |e^{-iz}|)/2 = (e^{-y}+e^y)/2.$$

Now $e^{-y}+e^y$ is even and increases on $[0,1].$ Since $|z|\le 1 $ implies $y\le 1,$ the right side of $(1)$ is bounded above by $(e^{-1}+e^1)/2 = (1+e^2)/(2e).$

Comment: I made an error in my first answer. It should be fine now.

Comment: Could you please give me more details about the final part of your argument? I can't understand why the right side of (1) is bounded $(e^{-1}+e^1)/2$. I understand that $y\leq1$ implies $e^y\leq e^1$, but how can this imply $e^{-y} \leq e^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

I was about to ask if you could have done something wrong when I saw you wrote $\frac{1}{2}(e^{-y}+e^{y})$, but I remembered that $y\leq1$ implies that $2y\leq2$ and $e^{2y} \leq e^2$, and therefore
$$|w|\leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{-y}+e^y)=\frac{e^{-y}}{2}(1+e^{2y})\leq\frac{1+e^2}{2e}$$

I got convinced

Comment: How did you get the last inequality?

Comment: $e^{-y}=\frac{1}{e^y}\<\frac{1}{e$}

Comment: What if $y=-1$ or $y=0?$

Comment: You're right :/